# Time-efficient way to count number of distinct numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

`get_number()` returns an integer. I'm going to call it 30 times and count the number of distinct integers returned. My plan is to put these numbers into an `std::array<int,30>`, sort it and then use `std::unique`.

Is that a good solution? Is there a better one? This piece of code will be the bottleneck of my program.

I'm thinking there should be a hash-based solution, but maybe its overhead would be too much when I've only got 30 elements?

**Edit** I changed *unique* to *distinct*. Example:

```
{1,1,1,1} => 1
{1,2,3,4} => 4
{1,3,3,1} => 2
```

Comment: Simplest solution: stick them in a `set`. Do you know the range of the numbers (e.g. they will be in `[0,255]`)?

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yes, they will.

Comment: call it 30 times will be the bottleneck?

Comment: @Andreas What do you mean "Yes, they will"? They will be in *some* known range (tell us what it is)? They will be in the specific range I pulled out of thin air?

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, it was a good guess. Actually [0,99], but I suppose that doesn't matter.

Comment: @billz Extracting the number of unique numbers will be, I think.

Comment: @Andreas: I have a doubt, are you trying to count the number of items which only appeared once, or the number of different items that appeared ? For example, with the sequence `[1, 1, 2]` there are 2 different items (`1` and `2`) but only 1 unique item (`2`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry, I see now that my question was unclear. I meant the former ({1,1,2} gives 2)

Comment: @Andreas: That's not the conventional meaning of "unique elements".

Comment: @Andreas And subsequently `{1,1,1}` would yield `0`, as would `{1,1,2,2}` correct ?

Comment: I have impression that you're wasting time. You have **only** 30 numbers, so no matter what you use, it is going to be fast enough.

Comment: @WhozCraig: according to his explanation, {1, 1, 1} would yield nothing. Because 0 is a number.

Comment: @SigTerm "... **count** the number of unique integers returned..." 0 seems a fine number to represent that.

Comment: I realise that the wording was unclear, but my example and algorithm should be understandable enough.

Comment: @SigTerm The code will run more than once, for different sets of 30 numbers.

Comment: @Andreas then a `set<int>` is sufficient

Comment: @Andreas: " more than once," If you aren't going to run it several millions of times per second, there's no real reason to worry about performance (for now). To count number of unique integers, use `std::set<int>.size()`

Comment: @Andreas If you have to run your code more than once then my solution may be more adapted to your needs due to the fact it uses constant memory. No allocation/deallocation. Using a `set` or `map` will allocate/deallocate memory in `O(N)` where `N` is the number of groups or 30 integers you have. To adapt my algorithm you just have to reset the values in the `cnt_buckets` vector between two groups of integers. This is a constant time operation because it depends only on the integer's range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `std::set<int>` as it's simpler:

```
std::set<int> s;
for(/*loop 30 times*/)
{
   s.insert(get_number());
}
std::cout << s.size() << std::endl; // You get count of unique numbers
```

If you want to count return times of each unique number, I'd suggest `map`

```
std::map<int, int> s;
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
  s[get_number()]++;
}

cout << s.size() << std::endl;  // total count of distinct numbers returned

for (auto it : s)
{
  cout << it.first << " " << it.second<< std::endl;  // each number and return counts
}
```

Comment: Though this is the accepted answer (and it is indeed a good one), have a look fjardon's approach further below. This is a case, in which the overhead of a tree (which `std::map` and `std::set` use internally) may lead to a far worse performance than even the simplest C style solution.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to use a `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, size_t> counters;

for (size_t i = 0; i != 30; ++i) {
    counters[getNumber()] += 1;
}

std::vector<int> uniques;
for (auto const& pair: counters) {
    if (pair.second == 1) { uniques.push_back(pair.first); }
}

// uniques now contains the items that only appeared once.
```

Comment: +1 Given the parameters of the OP's question, this seems the only viable answer that fits the requirements. The OP would have done well to phrase the question "how do i find the distinct elements that appear exactly once?"

Answer (score 3):

Using a `std::map`, `std::set` or the `std::sort` algorithm will give you a `O(n*log(n))` complexity. For a small to large number of elements it is perfectly correct. **But you use a known integer range and this opens the door to lot of optimizations.**

As you say (in a comment) that the range of your integers is known and short: `[0..99]`. I would recommend to implement a modified counting sort. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

You can count the number of distinct items while doing the sort itself, removing the need for the `std::unique` call. The whole complexity would be `O(n)`. Another advantage is that **the memory needed is independent of the number of input items**. If you had 30.000.000.000 integers to sort, it would not need a single supplementary byte to count the distinct items.

Even is the range of allowed integer value is large, says `[0..10.000.000]` the memory consumed would be quite low. Indeed, an optimized version could consume as low as 1 bit per allowed integer value. That is less than 2 MB of memory or 1/1000th of a laptop ram.

Here is a short example program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// A function returning an integer between [0..99]
int get_number()
{
    return rand() % 100;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // reserves one bucket for each possible integer
    // and initialize to 0
    std::vector<int> cnt_buckets(100, 0);
    int nb_distincts = 0;

    // Get 30 numbers and count distincts
    for(int i=0; i<30; ++i)
    {
        int number = get_number();
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
        if(0 == cnt_buckets[number])
            ++ nb_distincts;

        // We could optimize by doing this only the first time
        ++ cnt_buckets[number];
    }

    std::cerr << "Total distincts numbers: " << nb_distincts << std::endl;
}
```

You can see it working:

```
$ ./main | sort | uniq | wc -l
Total distincts numbers: 26
26
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to use `std::set`.

```
std::set<int> s;
int uniqueCount = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < 30; ++i )
{
    int n = get_number();

    if( s.find(n) != s.end() ) {
        --uniqueCount;
        continue;
    }

    s.insert( n );
}

// now s contains unique numbers
// and uniqueCount contains the number of unique integers returned
```

Comment: I do not see how, unless you plan on using two sets ?

Comment: It does not help as in fact I am confused by the question (maybe because I am not a native speaker), so I don't know what the OP is hoping to count. My initial thought was that he wanted to know the number of items that appeared once, but apparently everyone else is thinking that he wants to know the number of distinct items that appeared.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The algorithm the OP is proposing is counting the number of distinct items, so that is most likely what he wants to do.

Comment: @MatthieuM, maybe you're right, we should answer the question we are asked to. Updated my answer again.

Comment: @IvanGrynko: sometimes it's just difficult to understand what is asked :( btw, you could simplify your answer using the fact that `insert` returns `pair<iterator,bool>` and thus `if(not s.insert(n).second) { --uniqueCount; }` could replace most of the body loop (maybe not clearer though).

Comment: @MatthieuM, +1 your comment, but it's not so clear as the longer loop body :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an `array` and `sort` seems good, but `unique` may be a bit overkill if you just need to count distinct values. The following function should return number of distinct values in a sorted range.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
size_t distinct(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
  if (begin == end) return 0;

  size_t count = 1;
  ForwardIterator prior = begin;
  while (++begin != end)
  {
    if (*prior != *begin)
      ++count;

    prior = begin;
  }
  return count;
}
```

In contrast to the `set`- or `map`-based approaches this one does not need any heap allocation and elements are stored continuously in memory, therefore it should be much faster. Asymptotic time complexity is `O(N log N)` which is the same as when using an associative container. I bet that even your original solution of using `std::sort` followed by `std::unique` would be much faster than using `std::set`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a set, try an unordered set, try sort and unique, try something else that seems fun.

Then MEASURE each one. If you want the fastest implementation, there is no substitute for trying out real code and seeing what it really does.

Your particular platform and compiler and other particulars will surely matter, so test in an environment as close as possible to where it will be running in production.